# openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.List; change font size

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

On my WP8.1 phone, the font size in the control is way too big.
It lists only a partial name for long file names.
Is there any way to change the font size for the list?
Nothing obvious so far..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You can't change any UI elements in File/Folder Picker Windows.

Comment: Any workaround? The control doesn't even appear to be rotatable. Good only for 7.3 filenames or picture tiles.